# Azure Function With ServicueBusTrigger Behind Proxy Not working

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

From title It is evident that I have some issue related to proxy.

1. If I disable the proxy or machine without proxy, everything seems to be working fine.
2. When proxy and vpn enable at that time if I try to publish message or receive message via servicebustrigger in azure function not working.

- To the some extends for publish that issue can be resolved by creating ServiceBusClient and configuring the proxy for that.
- For ServiceBusTrigger there is no option to configure proxy setting or atleast I am not aware of that.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` extension used by the `ServiceBusTrigger` uses the `AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:ServiceBus` config section to build the Service Bus client used by the input binding: [ServiceBusHostBuilderExtensions.cs:44](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Config/ServiceBusHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L44)

You can therefore, configure the client to use the proxy by setting the "AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:ServiceBus:WebProxy" property in your `local.settings.json` file (or any other way you set your configuration):

```
"AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:ServiceBus:WebProxy": "<proxy address and port>",
```

Additionally, if your proxy does not allow you to use the AMPQS port (5671), you can configure the Service Bus client to use AMQP over Web Sockets (which uses port 443) by setting the `AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:ServiceBus:TransportType` property to `AmqpWebSockets`.

```
"AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:ServiceBus:TransportType": "AmqpWebSockets"
```

The environment used to test this:

- **Framework:** .NET 6 (in-process)
- **Azure Functions Version:** v4
- **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Function:** 4.0.1
- **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus:** 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

NServiceBus with Azure Functions is configured via `ServiceBusTriggeredEndpointConfiguration` which has a `Transport` property of `AzureServiceBusTransport` type. Using the `Transport` property, you should be able to specify the [connectivity](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/configuration#connectivity) by enabling WebSockets.

Comment: Thanks but this is somewhat different. Is there anyway we can know how servicebustrigger work from source code. I am not able to find anything in that regard like I find attribute but now actual implementation that poll from servicebus and trigger the function.

Comment: Service Bus trigger itself? That shouldn't be touched as it's controlled by the Azure environment and has no need to go over web sockets. Perhaps I don't quite grasp your question.

Comment: Problem is servicebustrigger is not working when it is behind proxy. Now if I create console application then I can use ServiceBusClient and it has proxy configuration so in that case it is working for WebSocket transport. I wonder is there any configuration for servicebustrigger with function boundary. Also this is main problem because for local development there is no sandbox that run locally for servicebus. ( Like for CosmosDB there is simulator so no need to go to azure for local development and it is not the case with servicebus)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but adding `;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets` to the connection string should in theory cause the trigger to use web sockets.  I am still investigating this myself - I have found that it can now peek successfully, but is failing to complete the read at the end.

I am configuring the proxy in the startup (using `[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]` and a class derived from `FunctionsStartup` - see "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions".

Comment: It seems that you are using dotnet runtime and I am using dotnet-isolated. This is surely a proxy issue but for HttpClient I can set but same proxy is not used in ServiceBusTrigger and even if you create pure console based webjob then also proxy setting works. So I wonder why there is no such option for functionapp.

Comment: I am still searching for the answer to that!  I'll post it here if I found out how.

Answer (score 0):

I used following startup class to set Amqp Web Socket transport and make it working for me when working locally behind the proxy.

```
using AzureFunctions;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace AzureFunctions
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            if (IsLocalDevelopmentEnvironment)
            {
                builder.AddServiceBus(options =>
                {
                    options.TransportType = Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
                });
            }
        }

        private bool IsLocalDevelopmentEnvironment => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development";
    }
}
```